# Подскажите какими способами можно добиться такого результата в input?

Tags: javascript

[image]

нужно, чтобы продукты при нажатии на enter разделялись на разные блоки внутри input, и соответственно на разные значения, для дальнейшего использования

Comment: Стандартным `input` не кастомизируешь таким образом. Нужно кастомный виджет использовать или готовые библиотеки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов, использовать библиотеку. Например эту: https://materializecss.com/chips.html

Comment: Писать ответ нужно так, чтобы отталкиваясь от него можно было бы написать решение. Подробнее можно ознакомится [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В справке написано: "Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным." В данной библиотеке, на которую я направил спрашивающего, есть вся необходимая информация для решения этого вопроса. (один из способов) В чём суть вашего замечания мне непонятно.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с частью справки где написано: `Оставляйте описание к ссылкам` и к её описанию, там понятно объяснено, что требуется от отвечающего.

Comment: Да, точно, упустил. Исправлюсь)

Comment: Надеюсь :) Единственное, что нужно это сам минимальный код с документации и объяснение к самому коду (на русском языке).